# Can I get atomization energy of a chemical?

Tags: chemistry, entity

A pretty basic property of a chemical is the atomization energy. Another similar property is the heat of formation.

I'm looking at

`EntityProperties[Entity["Chemical", "Ethane"]]`

I don't see atomization energy. Am I missing something? Or is there some way to get it indirectly?

EDIT: Wolfram Alpha can give me molar heats of formation so it seems plausible that I should be able to get them in the Wolfram Language but I don't see it.

Comment: From a quick reading of the definition of [`enthalpy of atomization`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_atomization), it appears that you are looking for the sum of the bond energies, i.e., `Total@Entity["Chemical","Ethane"]["BondEnergies"]` which evaluates to `Quantity[757., Kilojoules/Moles]` To check this you need a known value of atomization energy for a chemical.

Comment: The `BondEnergies` may or may not need to be multiplied by the `BondCounts` to get the total. Emphasizing that you need some known values to check the approach used.

Comment: Yes--after multiplying by bond counts, this is pretty close to the atomization enthalpies I get from [NIST](https://cccbdb.nist.gov/ea1.asp). Not a perfect comparison (energy vs enthalpy) but it's close enough to convince me there's something to it

Comment: @BobHanlon did you want to convert your comment to an answer to clean up this Q&A?

Comment: @bobthechemist - I recommend that the OP self-answer with whatever he finally used.